# Session id and csrf token not set in cookie

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am using django as backend and react as frontend,in local the session auth working fine,but when I deploy in secure mode(https) csrf and sesion id is not set in the cookie,but I recieve the response header for set-cookie.

frontend link : https://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
backend link : https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/

This is my setings.py file

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://xxxx.cloudfront.net",
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]

 # PROD ONLY
 CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
 SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
 CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
 SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = [
    "https://xxxx.cloudfront.net",
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://xxxx.cloudfront.net",
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['Content-Type', 'X-CSRFToken']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

[Set-Cookie in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruias.png)

Comment: Are the django backend and the react frontend running on the same domain name? If you set the cookies in react for say `domain.com` and the backend is on `api.com` then the cookies will not work. Same for subdomains, you will need `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ‘.domain.com’` starting with a dot.

Comment: No, I am using aws cloudfront link for frontend and aws api gateway link for backend